# How to get fileds inside the Any object

Tags: android, arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have JSON response like this

```
  {
  "facilities": [
    {
      "facility_id": "1",
      "name": "Property Type",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Apartment",
          "icon": "apartment",
          "id": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "exclusions": [
    [
      {
        "facility_id": "1",
        "options_id": "4"
      },
      {
        "facility_id": "2",
        "options_id": "6"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

If I convert this to data class, I get `List<Any>` for "exclusions".
How can i get the "facility_id" and "options_id" from the "exclusions".

Answer (score 0):

This is basic stuff learn it yourself:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respString);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("exclusions");
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String facilityID = jsonObject1.getString("facility_id");
            String options_id = jsonObject1.getString("options_id");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

because your `"exclusions"` is list of lists .
your models must look like this

```
data class BaseResponse(
        @SerializedName("facilities") private val facilites:List<Any>,
        @SerializedName("exclusions") private val exclusionsRoot:List<RootExclusions>
)
data class RootExclusions(
        private var exclusions: List<Exclusion>
)
data class Exclusion(
    @SerializedName("facility_id") private val facilityId:String,
    @SerializedName("options_id") private val optionsId:String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i].First you have to convert String to JSONObject.

ii].Select the "exclusions" and assign to JSONArray ,then iterate by using the length of Array.

iii]. By using index, you can get the required value.

Below code :

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respString);
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("exclusions");
        for (int i = 0; i <array.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String facility_id ,option_id;
            facility_id = jsonObject1.getString("facility_id");
            option_id = jsonObject1.getString("options_id");
            System.out.println("facility_id"+facility_id);
            System.out.println("option_id"+facility_id);
        }
```